# AngularJS $scope issues in tabset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-tabset

I have a problem trying to watch in my controller a collection generated by a filter in the view.

I store the filtered data in a variable :

```
 <table class="table">
     <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredCollection = (myCollection | filter: txtSearch)">
         <td ng-bind="item"></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

and I would like to subscribe to changes of 'filteredCollection ' in my controller :

```
$scope.$watchCollection('filteredCollection', function() {
    if (typeof($scope.filteredCollection) != 'undefined')
        console.log('Results changed : ' + $scope.filteredCollection.length);
});
```

I have set up [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hezwyjx1/) to show you my issue : my watch function is never called.

Fun Fact, it works when I remove all the `<tabset> <tab>` tags in my HTML. I think I messed up with the $scope, but I don't get why. Maybe the tabset create a new $scope child or something.

I hope you guys will find out what is going on here,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `filteredCollection` in an object, so the it will change the correct scope property:

```
$scope.obj = { filteredCollection : [] };
$scope.$watchCollection('obj.filteredCollection', function(newVal) {
    if (typeof($scope.obj.filteredCollection) != 'undefined')
        console.log('Results changed : ' + $scope.obj.filteredCollection.length);
});
```

In the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in obj.filteredCollection = (myCollection | filter: txtSearch)">
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrdk07s/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you explain why I have to do that ? Is it a matter of variable passed by reference / value ?

Comment: thats because ngRepeat create a child scope, and then your filteredCollection will be a property on that scope. If you define an obj on the parent scope, then every change will be written to that parent scope. see this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your thought that `tabset` and `tab` create new scopes. Because of that you are losing the context of `filteredCollection` since this is now being created in the context of the `tab` directives scope.

Angular fairly recently added `controllerAs` syntax that helps to avoid situations like this. It allows us to determine better which scope something is being executed in.

I have updated your jsFiddle with `controllerAs` syntax to show how this helps. The watch now fires as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/hezwyjx1/2/

Here is a resource for some help with controller as syntax:

http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: Thank you for this interesting approach, I didn't know this "controllerAs" thing, and the article was great. But in my case, I find this solution 'heavier' than putting the collection in an object

Answer (score 0):

This is an another post with the solution for this:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1553